# Can't get data from site using requests in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to get text from this [site](https://www.spaceweatherlive.com/includes/live-data.php?object=solar_flare&lang=EN). It is just a simple plain site with only text. When running the code below, the only thing it prints out is a newline. I should say that websites content/text is dynamic, so it changes over a few minutes. My `requests` module version is 2.27.1. I'm using Python 3.9 on Windows.

What could be the problem?

```
import requests

url='https://www.spaceweatherlive.com/includes/live-data.php?object=solar_flare&lang=EN'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36',
}

content=requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(content.text)
```

This is the example of how the website should look.
[image: Website screenshot]

Comment: If you were checking the error codes, you'd see that you're getting a "403 Forbidden".  What you need to do is provide a fake `User-Agent` string.

Comment: @TimRoberts I haven't gotten any errors. Can you provide the example code of how should the fake user agent look

Comment: It's not the User-Agent.  Anon Coward  has the right answer below.  All you need is the `Accept-Encoding` header.  With that, I can fetch using `wget` just fine.  And, you didn't "see" any error because you weren't LOOKING for errors.  `requests` doesn't raise an exception for HTTP errors.  You're expected to check `content.response`.

Answer (score 1):

That particular server appears to be gating responses not on the User-Agent, but on the Accept-Encoding settings.  You can get a normal response with:

```
import requests
url = "https://www.spaceweatherlive.com/includes/live-data.php?object=solar_flare&lang=EN"
headers = {
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
}
content = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(content.text)
```

Depending on how the server responds over time, you might need to install the `brotli` package to allow requests to decompress content compressed with it.

Comment: Most of the time I get normal response, but sometimes I just get Response 403. How do I utilize brotli to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add user-agent like below.

```
import requests

url = "https://www.spaceweatherlive.com/includes/live-data.php?object=solar_flare&lang=EN"

payload={}
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.29.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Host': 'www.spaceweatherlive.com',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
 }
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: I still get only newline printed

Comment: strange, i get the output for me.  can you check you are getting ```403``` when you ```print(content)```?

Comment: Yes, I get <Response [403]>

Comment: @DinoGržinić can you please paste and update the question along with user-agent part. so I can run that also and see what's causing this.

Comment: @shivankgtml I updated it now. For the `User Agent` value I just googled "my user agent".

Comment: Hi @DinoGržinić I have updated my answer, please check now.

Comment: Sometimes it outputs the content and sometimes Response 403